# How to grep within a grep

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have a bunch of massive text files, about 100MB each.

I want to grep to find entries that have 'INDIANA JONES' in it:

```
$ grep -ir 'INDIANA JONES' ./
```

Then, I would like to find the entries where there is the word `PORTUGAL` within 5,000 characters of the `INDIANA JONES` term. How would I do this?

```
# in pseudocode
grep -ir 'INDIANA JONES' ./ | grep 'PORTUGAL' within 5000 char
```

Comment: Can your "5000 char" requirement be phrased in terms of a number of lines?

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep`'s `-o` flag to output the 5000 characters surround the match, then search those characters for the second string. For example:

```
grep -ioE ".{5000}INDIANA JONES.{5000}" file.txt | grep "PORTUGAL"
```

If you need the original match, add the `-n` flag to the second `grep` and pipe into:

```
cut -f1 -d: > line_numbers.txt
```

then you could use `awk` to print those lines:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$0]; next } FNR in a' line_numbers.txt file.txt
```

To avoid the temporary file, this could be written like:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$0]; next } FNR in a' <(grep -ioE ".{50000}INDIANA JONES.{50000}" file.txt | grep -n "PORTUGAL" | cut -f1 -d:) file.txt
```

For multiple files, use `find` and a `bash` loop:

```
for i in $(find . -type f); do
    awk 'FNR==NR { a[$0]; next } FNR in a' <(grep -ioE ".{50000}INDIANA JONES.{50000}" "$i" | grep -n "PORTUGAL" | cut -f1 -d:) "$i"
done
```

Comment: I like this answer better than mine. Yes it's complicated to someone newer, but parsing 100MB isn't a trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

Consider installing ack-grep.

```
sudo apt-get install ack-grep
```

ack-grep is a more powerful version of grep.

There's no trivial solution to your question (that i can think of) outside of a full batch script, but you can use the -A and -B flags on ack-grep to specify a number of trailing or leading lines to output, resp.

This may not be a number of chars, but is a step further in that direction.

While this may not be a solution, it might give you some idea as to how to do this. Lookup filters like ack, awk, sed, etc. and see if you can find one with a flag for this kind of behaviour.

The ack-grep manual:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/ack-grep.1p.html

**EDIT:**

I think the sad news is, what you might think you're looking for is something like:

```
grep "\(INDIANA JONES\).\{1,5000\}PORTUGAL" filename
```

The problem is, even on a small file, querying this is going to be impossible time-wise.
I got this one to work with a different number. it's a size problem.

For such a large set of files, *you'll need to do this in more than one step.*

#### A Solution:

The only solution I know of is the leading and trailing output from ack-grep.

#### Step 1: how long are your lines?

If you knew how many lines out you had to go
(and you could estimate/calculate this a few ways) then you'd be able to grep the output of the first grep. Depending on what's in your file, you should be able to get a decent upper bound as to how many lines is 5000 chars (if a line has 100 chars average, 50+ lines should cover you, but if it has 10 chars, you'll need 500+).

You've got to determine the maximum number of lines that could be 5000 chars. You could guess or pick a high range if you like, but that'll be up to you. It's your data.

With that, call: (if you needed 100 lines for 5000 chars)

```
ack-grep -ira "PORTUGAL" -A 100 -B 100 filename
```

and

```
ack-grep -ira "INDIANA JONES" -A 100 -B 100 filename
```

replace the 100s with what you need.

#### Step 2: parse the output

you'll need to take the matches that ack-grep returns and parse them, looking for any matches again, within these sub-ranges.

Look for INDIANA JONES in the first PORTUGAL ack-grep match output, and look for PORTUGAL in the second set of matches.

This should take a bit more work, likely involving a bash script (I might see if I can get one working this week), but it solves your massive-data problem, by breaking it down into more manageable chunks.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. What would be the correct syntax with grep using a regex? `grep -ir '/INDIANA JONES.{1,5000}PORTUGAL/' ./` ??

Comment: None that GNU and BSD versions of `grep` support the `-A` and `-B` flags

Comment: No, they don't. Perhaps you fail to understand - I was speaking of ack-grep - when I said "the -A and -B flags on ack-grep....". I thought I was pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

One way to deal with this is with [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk). You could set the record separator to either `INDIANA JONES` or `PORTUGAL` and then perform a length check on the record (after stripping newlines, assuming newlines do not count towards the limit of 5000). You may have to resort to [find](/questions/tagged/find) to run this recursively within a directory

```
awk -v RS='INDIANA JONES|PORTUGAL' '{a = $0;
gsub("\n", "", a)};
((RT ~ /IND/ && prevRT ~/POR/) || (RT ~ /POR/ && prevRT ~/IND/)) && length(a) < 5000{found=1};
{prevRT=RT};
END{if (found) print FILENAME}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep 'INDIANA JONES' . -iR -l | while read filename; do head -c 5000 "$filename" | grep -n  PORTUGAL -H --label="$filename" ; done`

This works as follows:

- `grep 'INDIANA JONES' . -iR -l`.  Search for all files in or below the current directory.  Case insensitive (`-i`). And only print the names of the files that match (`-l`), don't print any content.
- `| while read filename; do ...|...|...; done` for each line of input, store it in variable `$filename` and execute the pipeline.

Now, for each file that matched 'INDIANA JONES', we do

- `head -c 5000 "$filename"` - extract the first 5000 characters
- `grep ...` - search for PORTUGAL. Print the filename (`-H`), but where we tell us the 'filename' we want to use with `--label="$filename"`.  Print line numbers too, `-n`.